# How to pass two inputs to %>% operator in R

Tags: r, pipe, readability

Originally I have this code which I am trying to simplify and improve readability using %>% operator.

```
#Get Sunday's from 2018-01-01 till today
d = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"),Sys.Date()+365,by='day')
HolidayList = data.frame(Holidays=d[weekdays(d)=='Sunday'])

#Get Alternate saturdays 2nd and 4th
d = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"),Sys.Date()+365,by='day')
saturdayList = d[weekdays(d)=='Saturday']
altSaturdayList = lapply(split(saturdayList, format(saturdayList, "%Y-%m")), function(x)
  na.omit(x[c(2,4)]))
altSaturdayList = as.data.frame(altSaturdayList)
altSaturdayList = gather(altSaturdayList)
altSaturdayList = subset(altSaturdayList,select = c(value))
HolidayList = rbind(HolidayList, setNames(altSaturdayList, "Holidays"))
HolidayList = rbind(HolidayList, setNames(as.data.frame(as.Date("2018-11-06")), "Holidays"))
HolidayList = unique(HolidayList)
HolidayList = arrange(HolidayList,Holidays)
rm(d)
rm(saturdayList)
rm(altSaturdayList)
```

I don't want to store the intermediate variables that's why I thought pipe operator would be a good choice but I am not able to reproduce the result.

Here's what I tried

```
HolidayList = saturdayList %>% 
    data.frame(lapply(split(saturdayList, format(saturdayList, "%Y-%m")), function(x)
    na.omit(x[c(2,4)]))) %>% 
    subset(gather(altSaturdayList),select = c(value)) %>% 
    rbind(HolidayList, setNames(altSaturdayList, "Holidays")) %>% 
    rbind(HolidayList, setNames(as.data.frame(as.Date("2018-11-06")), "Holidays")) %>% 
    arrange(unique(HolidayList),Holidays)
```

`Holidays` dataframe has dates to which I am trying to bind and add new dates.

How do I take output of each step and put as input in next line without creating new variables?

Please explain the steps so that I can understand the process to simplify above code.

Comment: Where is HolidayList coming from? You're calling it up out of nowhere.

Comment: @Phil sorry I missed that. Added it now. it's a dataframe with Sunday dates in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are functions which are specially designed for pipe operators in `tidyverse`. Those functions are well suited for using pipe operators instead of using base R operators and trying to fit them in pipe. You can still use base R functions in pipe but it is more convenient to use them using `tidyverse` tools.

```
library(tidyverse)

temp <- map_dfr(split(saturdayList,format(saturdayList, "%Y-%m")), ~ .[c(2, 4)]) %>%
    gather(key, Holidays) %>%
    select(Holidays) %>%
    bind_rows(HolidayList) %>%
    add_row(Holidays = as.Date("2018-11-06")) %>%
    unique() %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    arrange(Holidays) 

temp

#   Holidays  
#   <date>    
# 1 2018-01-07
# 2 2018-01-13
# 3 2018-01-14
# 4 2018-01-21
# 5 2018-01-27
# 6 2018-01-28
# 7 2018-02-04
# 8 2018-02-10
# 9 2018-02-11
#10 2018-02-18
# … with 160 more rows
```

To confirm if output from both of them is the same we can convert `temp` to data frame and then compare to `HolidayList` in your final step.

```
identical(data.frame(temp), HolidayList)
#[1] TRUE
```